# Python Read unique CSV Values for Loop

Tags: python, csv

I have 3 CSVs that are being generated that I'm looking to combine into one. I only need certain columns from each file but I need them to match up on the switch number and the interface

File1

```
switch1,Gi1/0/22,connected,716,a-full,a-100,10/100/1000BaseTX
switch2,Fa3/0/8,connected,716,a-full,a-100,10/100BaseTX
switch3,Fa2/0/5,connected,716,a-full,a-100,10/100BaseTX
```

File2

```
switch1,716,0040.0020.0010,DYNAMIC,Gi1/0/22
switch2,716,0030.0020.1010,DYNAMIC,Fa3/0/8
switch3,716,0050.0030.1010,DYNAMIC,Fa2/0/5
```

File3

```
switch1,Gi1/0/22,0,32,0,33,0,9
switch2,Fa3/0/8,0,0,0,0,0,362
switch3,Fa2/0/5,0,10,20,0,0,100
```

I'm trying to get the final csv to look like this:

```
switch1,Gi1/0/22,0040.0020.0010,0,32,0,33,0,9
switch2,Fa3/0/8,0030.0020.1010,0,0,0,0,0,362
switch3,Fa2/0/5,0050.0030.1010,0,10,20,0,0,100
```

which is the switch name, interface, 3rd column of File2, and columns 3-8 from File3

Not looking for an exact answer if you don't want to give it, but more of a general idea/direction. Still pretty new to python.

Comment: You might want to have a look at pandas. You can read each file as a separate dataframe, combine them and write the final csv.

read_csv, merge and to_csv are the methods you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with pandas or with the standard library. Pandas is generally a lot faster and easier to read.

Setup:

```
from textwrap import dedent

def write_file(name, string):
    with open(name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(dedent(string).lstrip())

write_file('File1.csv', """
    switch1,Gi1/0/22,connected,716,a-full,a-100,10/100/1000BaseTX
    switch2,Fa3/0/8,connected,716,a-full,a-100,10/100BaseTX
    switch3,Fa2/0/5,connected,716,a-full,a-100,10/100BaseTX
""")

write_file('File2.csv', """
    switch1,716,0040.0020.0010,DYNAMIC,Gi1/0/22
    switch2,716,0030.0020.1010,DYNAMIC,Fa3/0/8
    switch3,716,0050.0030.1010,DYNAMIC,Fa2/0/5
""")

write_file('File3.csv', """
    switch1,Gi1/0/22,0,32,0,33,0,9
    switch2,Fa3/0/8,0,0,0,0,0,362
    switch3,Fa2/0/5,0,10,20,0,0,100
""")
```

Pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd

t1 = pd.read_csv('File1.csv', names=['switch_name', 'interface', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7'])
t2 = pd.read_csv('File2.csv', names=['switch_name', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'interface'])
t3 = pd.read_csv('File3.csv', names=['switch_name', 'interface', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8'])

result = t2[['switch_name', 'interface', 'col3']].merge(t3, on=['switch_name', 'interface'])
result.to_csv('Final.csv', header=False, index=False)

with open('Final.csv') as f:
    print f.read()

# switch1,Gi1/0/22,0040.0020.0010,0,32,0,33,0,9
# switch2,Fa3/0/8,0030.0020.1010,0,0,0,0,0,362
# switch3,Fa2/0/5,0050.0030.1010,0,10,20,0,0,100
```

Standard library code:

```
import csv

# store data in a dictionary for later reference
with open('File3.csv') as f:
    f3_data = {(r[0], r[1]): r[2:8] for r in csv.reader(f)}

with open('File2.csv') as f2, open('Final.csv', 'w') as f:
    final = csv.writer(f)
    for switch_name, col2, col3, col4, interface in csv.reader(f2):
        if (switch_name, interface) in f3_data:
            final.writerow([switch_name, interface, col3] + f3_data[switch_name, interface])

with open('Final.csv') as f:
    print f.read()

# switch1,Gi1/0/22,0040.0020.0010,0,32,0,33,0,9
# switch2,Fa3/0/8,0030.0020.1010,0,0,0,0,0,362
# switch3,Fa2/0/5,0050.0030.1010,0,10,20,0,0,100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first open the 3 files at once, read them into nested list of lines with the `csv` libary, then extract the columns you need and write them to a file:

```
from csv import reader

# open all files at once
with open('file1.csv') as f1, \
     open('file2.csv') as f2, \
     open('file3.csv') as f3:

     # convert them to reader objects
     csv_files = reader(f1), reader(f2), reader(f3)

     # open file to write to
     with open('combined.csv', 'w') as out:

         # go over each row from the files at once using zip()
         for row1, row2, row3 in zip(*csv_files):

             # extract columns into a list
             line = row1[:2] +[row2[2]] +  row3[3:]

             # write to the file
             out.write(','.join(line) +'\n')

# print contents of new file
print(open('combined.csv').read())
```

Which Outputs:

```
switch1,Gi1/0/22,0040.0020.0010,0,32,0,33,0,9
switch2,Fa3/0/8,0030.0020.1010,0,0,0,0,0,362
switch3,Fa2/0/5,0050.0030.1010,0,10,20,0,0,100
```

Comment: That would work assuming all the `csv`s are in the same order.  But if any of the `csv` is in a different order it'll have a mismatch.

Comment: @Idlehands That's true. OP really hasn't specified this. This should give a good base on solving the problem.